# Given $aabb$ is a square number, and $a := b$, find $a$ and $b$.

Tags: contest-math

I want to solve the above question systematically, i.e, assuming that I do not know all the $4$-digit square numbers.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thanks, I just edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: related/duplicate: [2013](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571582/find-the-four-digit-number/1033863#1033863), [2015](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354718/find-the-number-ccbb/1354728#1354728), [2016](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969595/how-to-find-a-number-aabb-that-is-a-perfect-square/1969617#1969617), [2018](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732206/is-there-any-way-to-solve-this-problem/2732232#2732232)

Comment: Since you know that $a=b$ why don't you just write it as $aaaa$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$aabb=1100a+11b=11(100a+b)$$

then we need

$$11|100a+b \iff a+b\equiv0 \pmod{11}$$

moreover

$$1100a+11b\equiv 0,1 \pmod 4 \iff 3b \equiv 0,1 \pmod 4 \iff b \equiv 0,3 \pmod 4$$

but since squares doesn't end with $3$, $7$ or $8$ then we need to check among

- $0000,7744$

Comment: squares don't end in $3$, $7$ or $8$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes of course! I fix that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Remember that your number can be written in the form
$$z=b+10b+100a+1000a=11b+1100a$$